# Do we want to allow story-identification questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[A first story-identification question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15508/2594) has just been asked and I think it would be best to discuss here whether we want to allow such questions and if yes, under which conditions.

Note that identification questions are on topic on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/identify-this-movie/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. We want to discuss the language; not stories that have been written in that language.

Answer (score 1):

Such questions could *discuss the finer points of German language* insofar as we could analyze their vocabulary, style and rhetoric figures to make out the author. So if the text

- is (almost) complete and
- seems to be a piece of poetry, drama or major form prose,

then I think we should give it a shot. We could actually rediscover some art pieces for the internet. Apart from that I don't see any danger of getting overwhelmed by such questions.

Answer (score 0):

No

Aside from the fact,  that these questions do not discuss the german language, they are also alredy on topic at multiple sites better suited for this.

These sites are off the top of my head:

- Anime & Manga
- SciFi
- Movies

Comment: Such questions are only on topic on these sites, if the story or its medium match the site’s scope. The story in the exapmle question, e.g., would not be on-topic on neither site.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft from what I see, this looks okay for scifi, they require more details for identification, though.

Comment: I do not see any hint that the story in the question can be classified as science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft point taken.. [Books.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61293/books) is in definition...